# Can arbitrary objects be made reactive in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**I am looking for ways to optimize sorting normalized objects by a relationship.** Let's pretend that one has an app that needs to sort 
I have a Vuex store that contains many normalized objects, like so:

```
state: {
    worms: {
        3: { id: 3, name: 'Slurms McKenzie', measurements: [1, 6, 9]  },
        4: { id: 4, name: 'Memory worm',  measurements: [3, 4, 12] },
        6: { id: 6, name: 'Alaskan Bull Worm', measurements: [5, 7, 14]},
        ...
    },
    measurements: {
        1: { id: 1, length: 5.2, timestamp: ...},
        2: { id: 2, length: 3.4, timestamp: ...},
        3: { id: 3, length: 5.4, timestamp: ...},
        ...
    },
};
```

Say I need to sort my `worms` on the `timestamp` that they reached their highest length. Being steeped in Vue's reactivity, I would love to be able to defined a getter on each worm, like this:

```
const getters = {
    longestLength: {
        get() { return $store.getters
                    .measurements(this.measurements)
                    .sort(...)[0] },
     },

     timestampForLongest: {
         get() { return this.longestLength.timestamp }
}

worm.extend(getters);
```

I could then easily and quickly sort on `timestampForLongest` assuming the value is cached.

I have a great entry point to call this `extend` (or whatever it ends up being called), but I have a few challenges.

1. The way I handle this now is by calculating a denormalized map and then sorting based on this. The latency is ~700ms on my 8th gen Intel processor in Chrome, which I'd really like to cut down on.
2. I don't know how to invoke Vue's reactivity system manually. I believe that I need to define getters that call something like `measurement.__ob__.dep.depend()` but I haven't wrapped my head around it.
3. The API to achieve this may be private and subject to change. Is Vue just too slow to handle 800+ rows?
4. I don't know how to keep the Vuex store (`$store`) in scope for the getters. I could probably use arrow functions, so I'm not as worried about this.

Can I calculate and cache values on demand in plain javascript objects using Vue?

Comment: I don't understand ... first, how do you populate your **Vue app**? where is you **Vue app**? what is `worm`? Is `worm` your **Vue app**??

Comment: `state` is part of a Vuex store. The store is populated through various methods, like `fetch` requests and WebSockets. My Vue app is hosted on a server. In the latter example, `extend` is intended in the traditional sense of assigning attributes to a javascript object, not creating a component instance as in the Vue API. I agree this could be confusing, but try to think of it as extending additional methods to what would otherwise be a plain Object.

Comment: I added a solution~

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has syntax errors, they had to be corrected:

```js
const states = {
  worms: {
    3: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Slurms McKenzie',
      measurements: [1, 6, 9]
    },
    4: {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Memory worm',
      measurements: [3, 4, 12]
    },
    6: {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Alaskan Bull Worm',
      measurements: [5, 7, 14]
    }
  },
  measurements: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      length: 5.2,
      timestamp: 'ts1'
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      length: 3.4,
      timestamp: 'ts2'
    },
    3: {
      id: 3,
      length: 5.4,
      timestamp: 'ts3'
    },
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: states,
  getters: {
    getWorms: state => {
      return state.worms
    },
    getLongestLengthByMeasurementId: state => ids => {
      const mapped = ids.map(id => {
        const measurement = state.measurements[id]
        if (measurement) {
          return {
            length: measurement.length || 0,
            timestamp: measurement.timestamp || 0
          }
        } else {
          return {
            length: 0,
            timestamp: 0
          }
        }
      })
      return mapped.find(item => item.length === Math.max.apply(null, mapped.map(item => item.length))).timestamp
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    // setting timestamp in store.state.worms[wormId]
    setLongestLength(state, wormId) {
      if (state.worms[wormId] && typeof state.worms[wormId].timestamp !== 'undefined') {
        // update the timestamp
      } else {
        // get and set the timestamp 
        const ts = store.getters.getLongestLengthByMeasurementId(state.worms[wormId].measurements)
        Vue.set(state.worms[wormId], 'timestamp', ts)
      }
    },
  },
  actions: {
    // set timestamp worm by worm
    setLongestLength({
      commit
    }, wormId) {
      Object.keys(store.getters.getWorms).forEach(key =>
        commit('setLongestLength', parseInt(key, 10))
      )
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    store.dispatch('setLongestLength')
    console.log('worms', store.state.worms)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="worm in $store.state.worms">Timestamp by worm (ID {{worm.id}}): {{worm.timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

You only need to add `get:` in your getter if you also use a `set:`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I need the timestamp for each worm's longest length in a performant way. The state is denormalized and cannot (and should not) be reimplemented as array members. 

What I'm trying to understand is how I can cache a calculated value in a more global way.

Comment: The code is updated - if you want the longest length, then you don't need sorting. Of course, if you wanted to use other attributes of a sorted array, then you could.

Comment: And getters are cached ("Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed." - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

Comment: Timestamp is returned with the getter. I think the `Object.values.map()` is needed, so the object becomes an array that can be fed to `find()`.

Comment: OK - now the timestamp is set (reactively) to all worms.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this might help. I don't know the whole structure of your project but I tried to recreated here and this is one approach.

You've defined a `state` that contains `worms` and `measurements` lists. Each `worm` has a measurement list of indexes, which I suppose it is related with the `measurements` list.

Now `state` should be defined inside of the your Vuex `store`. Now, your `store` will have four main elements which includes: state, getters, actions, and mutations.

So the `state`, in essence, can be viewed as a single source of truth for the entire application. **But how can our components and routes access the data stored in our state?** Well, the `getters` will return the data from our `store` back to our components, in this case we want to get the `sortedByTSDec` and `sortedByTSAsc` methods.
So, now you have figured out how to **get** data from the `state`, let’s see how we can **set** data into our `state`. You must be think **I can define setters, right?** Well, no, Vuex **"setters"** are named slightly different. You should define a `mutation` to set data into your `state`.
Finally, `actions` are similar to `mutations`, but instead of mutating the `state` directly they commit a mutation. **Confused?** Just, think about `actions` like **asynchronous** functions while `mutations` are **synchronous**.
In this example, I don't know where the worms data is being generation it can be from another server, a database, and so on. So the `generateData` action will request and wait for the data and when the data is ready will call the `populate` mutation to populate the `state`.

#### So what about the `Worn` class?

Here is where the **magic** happens. The `Vue.extend()` method create a ***subclass*** of the base Vue constructor. ***But why?*** Because this subclass has a `data` option. When we set this value in the `populate` mutation with the data of a generated worn. In other words the `state.worms` contains a list of `Worn` objects.
Also, we declare the `computed` properties to calculate the `longestLength` and `timestampForLongest` with the data of the instance.

Now if you want to sort the `worms` list by the timestamp of its longest length then first we need to calculate the longest length, then we use the `.sort()` method. This method by default sorts values as strings. Therefore, we need to provide a **compare function** The purpose of the compare function is to define an alternative sort order. This function should return a negative, zero, or positive value, depending on the arguments. In this case we used `b.timestampForLongest - a.timestampForLongest` for decreasing order, but you can use `a.timestampForLongest - b.timestampForLongest` for ascending order.

Here is a basic snippet:

```js
const randomDate = function (start, end) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())).getTime()/1000;
};

const Worm = Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    longestLength() {
      let longest;
      for (const id of this.measurements) {
        const measurement = store.state.measurements[id];
        if (!longest || measurement.length > longest.length) {
          longest = measurement;
        }
      }

      return longest;
    },
    timestampForLongest() {
      return this.longestLength.timestamp
    },
  },
});


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    worms: {},
    measurements: {},
  },
  actions: {
    generateData({commit}) {
      const worms = [];
      for (let w = 0; w < 800; ++w) {
        const measurements = []
        for (let m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
          measurements.push({
            length: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 10,
            timestamp: randomDate(new Date(2018, 1, 1), new Date()),
          });
        }
        worms.push({
          id: w,
          name: 'Worm Name ' + w,
          measurements,
        });
      }

      commit('populate', worms)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    populate(state, worms) {
      const wormList = {};
      const measurementList = {};
      let measurementId = 0;

      for (let worm of worms) {
        const measurementIds = [];
        for (let measurement of worm.measurements) {
          measurementId++
          measurementIds.push(measurementId)
          measurementList[measurementId] = {
            id: measurementId,
            ...measurement,
          }
        }

        wormList[worm.id] = new Worm({
          data: {
            ...worm,
            measurements: measurementIds,
          }
        });
      }

      state.worms = wormList;
      state.measurements = measurementList;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    sortedByTSDec(state) {
      return Object.values(state.worms).sort((a, b) => b.timestampForLongest - a.timestampForLongest);
    },
    sortedByTSAsc(state) {
      return Object.values(state.worms).sort((a, b) => a.timestampForLongest - b.timestampForLongest);
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    sortedState() {
      return this.$store.getters.sortedByTSDec;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calculate() {
      this.$store.dispatch('generateData');
    },
    timestamp2Date(ts) {
      let newDate = new Date();
      newDate.setTime(ts * 1000);
      return newDate.toUTCString();
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="calculate">Get the Longest</button>
  <div v-for="worm in sortedState">
    {{ worm.name }} has its longest length of {{ worm.longestLength.length }}cm at  {{ timestamp2Date(worm.longestLength.timestamp) }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is somewhere close to what you had in mind.

If I've understood correctly, your intent was to create 'computed properties' (or getters of some kind) called `longestLength` and `timestampForLongest` on each worm. These would derive their values based on the `measurements` in the `state`.

I've attempted to do this by making each worm a Vue instance. Obviously there's a lot of other functionality that a Vue instance provides, such as rendering, that isn't needed in this case. In Vue 2 there isn't any way to single out just the bits you need. Rumour has it Vue 3 may be more modular in this regard. The only bits we need are observable `data` (which could be implemented using `Vue.observable`) and computed properties (which are only available via a Vue instance). For what it's worth, this is how Vuex works behind the scenes, creating a separate Vue instance and plugging into the data, computed, etc..

While the code below looks long, much of it is concerned with generating suitable test data. I initially generate data with measurements nested inside the worms and then pull it out to the format you've specified inside my mutation. Each instance inside `worms` is converted to a Vue instance before it is added to the `state`.

I've added `// This bit is important` comments to particularly important sections to make it easier to pick them out of the noise.

```js
// This bit is important
const Worm = Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    longestLength () {
      let longest = null

      for (const id of this.measurements) {
        const measurement = store.state.measurements[id]

        if (!longest || measurement.length > longest.length) {
          longest = measurement
        }
      }

      return longest
    },

    timestampForLongest () {
      return this.longestLength.timestamp
    }
  }
})


const state = {
  worms: {},
  measurements: {}
};

const mutations = {
  populate (state, worms) {
    const wormState = {}
    const measurementsState = {}
    let measurementId = 0

    for (const worm of worms) {
      const measurementIds = []

      for (const measurement of worm.measurements) {
        measurementId++
        measurementIds.push(measurementId)
        measurementsState[measurementId] = {id: measurementId, ...measurement}
      }

      // This bit is important
      wormState[worm.id] = new Worm({
        data: {...worm, measurements: measurementIds}
      })
    }

    state.worms = wormState
    state.measurements = measurementsState
  }
};

const getters = {
  // This bit is important
  sortedWorms (state) {
    return Object.values(state.worms).sort((wormA, wormB) => wormA.timestampForLongest - wormB.timestampForLongest)
  }
};

const actions = {
  populateWorms ({commit}) {
    const worms = []

    for (let wIndex = 0; wIndex < 800; ++wIndex) {
      const measurements = []

      for (let mIndex = 0; mIndex < 3; ++mIndex) {
        measurements.push({
          length: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 10,
          timestamp: Math.round(Math.random() * 1e6)
        })
      }

      worms.push({
        measurements,
        name: 'Worm ' + wIndex,
        id: wIndex
      })
    }

    commit('populate', worms)
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,

  computed: {
    sortedWorms () {
      return this.$store.getters.sortedWorms
    }
  },

  methods: {
    go () {
      this.$store.dispatch('populateWorms')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="go">Go</button>
  <div v-for="worm in sortedWorms">
    {{ worm.name }} - {{ worm.longestLength }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Whether or not this is actually a good way to implement all of this given your underlying requirement of optimum sorting I'm not so sure. However, it seemed as close as I could get to your intent of implementing computed properties on each worm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a totally different approach:
1. Avoid sorting by any means
2. Instead, have properties corresponding to max_length and max_time on each worm object and update them (max properties) whenever a new observation is posted (or recorded) for that worm

This way, you can avoid sorting each time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I make a Vue application with a lot of data such as yours, I'll do something like this:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      worms: [
        {id: 1,name: "Slurms McKenzie",measurements: [1, 6, 9]},
        {id: 2,name: "Memory worm",measurements: [3, 4, 12]},
        {id: 3,name: "Alaskan Bull Worm",measurements: [5, 7, 14]}
      ],

      measurements: [
        {id: 1,length: 5.2,timestamp: 123},
        {id: 2,length: 3.4,timestamp: 456},
        {id: 3,length: 5.4,timestamp: 789}
      ]
    };
  },

  computed: {
    sortedByLength() {
      return [...this.measurements]
        .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
        .map(measurement => measurement.id)
        .map(id => this.worms.find(worm => worm.id === id));
    },

    timestampForLongest() {
      return this.sortedByLength[0].timestamp;
    }
  }
});
```

Vue will update computed properties that change, and cache them otherwise. All you need to do is convert this into state/getters for Vuex and the principles are the same.

Storing them as arrays is much easier to handle than as objects. If you must use objects, you could probably use the lodash library to help you sort without it being obnoxious.